# While installing openedx i am getting this error

Tags: linux-kernel, edx, apparmor

```
TASK: [edxapp | code sandbox | (bootstrap) load code sandbox profile] ********* 
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["apparmor_parser", "-r", "/etc/apparmor.d/code.sandbox"], "delta": "0:00:00.003679", "end": "2014-07-06 00:13:35.972487", "item": "", "rc": 1, "start": "2014-07-06 00:13:35.968808"}                                                                               
stderr: Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.                                                                         

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting                                                       

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/edx_sandbox.retry
```

This is first time i am playing with edx. I dont know how to fix this error. And when i go to webaddress at port 80 it ask for username and password.

I am using a virtual machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue, had exactly the same. You are using OpenVZ container?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openedx-ops/R4TEXqpN38Y